# Dart - Creating new objects changes old objects

Tags: dart, oop

Running this in DartPad, why does object `a` get updated by succeeding declarations and instantiations of the same object type? How do I prevent the first objects from being updated?

```
void main() {
  SampleClass a = SampleClass(publicParam: 'A');
  print('1. a: ${a.getPrivateProperty}');

  SampleClass b = SampleClass(publicParam: 'B');
  print('2. a: ${a.getPrivateProperty}');
  print('3. b: ${b.getPrivateProperty}');

  SampleClass(publicParam: 'C');
  print('4. a: ${a.getPrivateProperty}');
  print('5. b: ${b.getPrivateProperty}');
}

class SampleClass {
  final String publicParam;
  static late String _privateProperty;

  SampleClass({
    required this.publicParam,
  }) {
    _privateProperty = publicParam;
  }

  // Getter
  String get getPrivateProperty => _privateProperty;
}
```

Output:

```
1. a: A
2. a: B
3. b: B
4. a: C
5. b: C
```

Can someone please help me as detailed as possible? Thank you so much. I think it's got to do with the constructor but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that your `_privateProperty` property is **static**, which means it is shared across all instances of the class.

I do not know your motivation of having another private property, but assuming you need it I would rewrite your class like this:

```dart
class SampleClass {
  final String publicParam;

  final String _privateProperty;

  SampleClass({
    required this.publicParam,
  }) : _privateProperty = publicParam;

  // Getter
  String get getPrivateProperty => _privateProperty;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I needed a private property so that I can implement listeners to the changes to that property.